# How to stop user from inputting text in the text field in the certain range.?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a doubt that how can I stop user from inputting anything in the text field after he enter 8 digits? Meaning the keyboard will be disable after the text field length reaches 8 digits , but if the user deletes any digit, the keyboard enable again?

Here is the code. Please help me out, thanks in advance. Currently, it only stops until 8 digits, but it does not allow me to delete anymore.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:DIGIT_CHARSET];
    NSString *text = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[charSet invertedSet]];

    if ([textField.text length] == 8) {
        return NO;
    }else 
    {
        return [text isEqualToString:string];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your code. it will not Allow to write any digits after 8, but if you delete then it will allow you to write the digits untill it is 8.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (range.location > 7)
        return NO;
    else
        return YES; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check length of changed text in textField.

```
NSString* changedText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange: range withString: string];
if ([changedText length] >= 8)
    return NO;
```